# Apache 2.4 updated, now throws: Cannot define multiple Listeners on the same IP:port

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, virtualhost, httpd.conf, port-443

I've just updated Apache to 2.4.3 on my AWS instance (running Linux AMI). After the update finished, Apache crashed with the following:

```
Starting httpd: AH00526: Syntax error on line 5 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
Cannot define multiple Listeners on the same IP:port
```

I went into the above file and commented out line 5: `#Listen 443`, because the new `httpd.conf` contains a line where the above listener is already set:

httpd.conf:

```
 40 ...
 41 #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
 42 Listen 80
 43 Listen 443
 44 
 45 ...
```

**My question is**, if I configure SSL certificates individually in my VirtualHost's config files, could I just comment out every line in the httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf? I mean is it still important to have it included? And why Apache 2.4.3 sets `Listen 443` twice?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps, during the upgrade, an old configuration file wasn't removed because of changes that were made to it since the previous version was installed?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille The same happened to me when I migrated Debian versions that upgraded Apache. It is indeed a matter of conflict between configuration files of different Apache versions.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro  In your case, it wasn't because you'd changed config files?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille To put it simply, yeah. That server was already a migration from something more older.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille yes, the old config file wasn't removed, probably this was the reason of the conflict. And regarding my second question, is the `httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` needed if I use to configure SSL in my VirtualHost's config files?

Comment: Needed, no, but you could use it for those settings valid for all VH's.

Answer (score 5):

I have got the same error on different file

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 18 of /private/etc/apache2/other/httpd_xcs.conf:
Cannot define multiple Listeners on the same IP:port
```

I just comment #Listen 443 and it worked fine.

Comment: thansk it worked for me too

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem under Windows 10 Server with Apache 2.4 installation. Problem ist that there's only one port-binding allowed.

The default **httpd.conf** has at the end the following section:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
Listen 443
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-ahssl.conf
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
<IfModule http2_module>
    ProtocolsHonorOrder On
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
</IfModule>
```

As you can see there's one port-binding at the second line and two other `Listen 443` in the `conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` and `conf/extra/httpd-ahssl.conf`.

You can either comment out the corresponding port-binding in the `httpd.conf` or inside the included config files.

Answer (score 2):

You can check which port has been consumed by which file by:

sudo grep -r "Listen" /etc/apache2/

and then comment out port which has been listened multiple times (which you don't want) to remove the conflict

Comment: This was totally helpful, it seems newer versions of apache have some defaults set in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` that I hadn't noticed or anticipated